# What can cause a CSS text-decoration line (underline) to appear splitted in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cross-browser, text-decorations

I use Windows10 home with latest Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Microsoft Edge.

I have a WordPress website in which the site-name (the uppermost text in the site) is just an `a` nested inside a `div`.

I gave the aforementioned `a` the `text-decoration: underline` CSS directive.

### My problem

Only in Google Chrome, the line appears splitted when I hover over `a` link:

[image]

3 classes of lines instead just one long line.

---

### Reproducing

Create a WordPress site on a supporting server envrionment. Change language to Hebrew, Install the *Elementor* page builder plugin + the Header Footer Elementor (HFE) plugin, create a header with a `div` and `a` inside it respectively, give the `a` some Hebrew text, link it to the site's domain and give it CSS directions.

### What I Tried to solve it

I basically tried nothing because I have no idea what may help solving it.

### My question

What may cause the text-decoration line to appear splitted?

Comment: Have you tried changing the text to "normal" Latin (i.e. basic ASCII) characters to check if the issue is still there? It may have to do with chrome's rendering engine not wanting to "cut" through longer glyphs with the underline.

Comment: Indeed, with normal Latin letters the problem **doesn't** happen. Is there nothing to do for Hebrew?

Comment: Apparently it's supposed to be a "feature" of chrome called "ink skipping", and it's fairly new. See this: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0FVZkW0RnDK4/?hl=en

Comment: In fact, it happens with Latin characters to, like `p` or `g` - I'm using chrome and I just noticed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of your browser.
One way you can fix this is using

`text-decoration-skip-ink: none;`

Or, if you find it ugly then you could use `border-bottom`

you can read about skip ink [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/#text-decoration-skip-ink-property)